# Linear interpolation of the 4D array in Python/NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, 4d

I have a question about the linear interpolation in python\numpy. 
I have a 4D array with the data (all data in binary files) that arrange in this way:
t- time (lets say each hour for a month = 720)
Z-levels (lets say Z'=7)
Y-data1 (one for each t and Z)
X-data2 (one for each t and Z)

So, I want to obtain a new Y and X data for the Z'=25 with the same t.

The first thing, I have a small trouble with the right way to read my data from the binary file. Second, I have to interpolate first 3 levels to Z'=15 and others for the other values.

If anyone has an idea how to do it and can help it will be great. 
Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

You can create different interpolation formulas for different combinations of z' and t.

For example, for `z=7`, and a specific value of `t`, you can create an interpolation formula:

```
formula = scipy.interp1d(x,y)
```

Another one for say `z=25` and so on.

Then, given any combination of z and t, you can refer to the specific interpolation formula and do the interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

In 2D for instance there is [bilinear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) - with an example on the unit square with the z-values 0, 1, 1 and 0.5 as indicated. Interpolated values in between represented by colour:

[image]

Then [trilinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_interpolation), and so on...

***Follow the pattern and you'll see that you can nest interpolations to any dimension you require***...

:)